# preventing child process becoming an orphan process

Tags: c, linux, process, init

My Linux process has 4 children. After some execution time all children adopted by the init process. How do we prevent this situation?  (this is not the case with Zombie processes).

The process is written in C and the OS is Linux. My code calls waitpid! What might be the problem? In 99,99% we don't have this problem.

Last update: What if someone executes "kill -9 "? This terminates immediately the parent process and leaves the children orphan.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your processes are being reparented by `init`, that means that their parent process has died.  When a process' parent dies, `init` adopts it so that it can reap the zombie by `wait()`ing on the child when it (that is, `init`) receives `SIGCHLD`.

If you do not want `init` to become the parent of your children, you will have to ensure that your process lives until all of your children have died and been reaped by your program.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the children to exit before exiting yourself. See the `wait(2)` man page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check from main page for your waitpid API parameters, and make sure your parent process should not be over before all child processes are finished.
Can you post your code here?